# Is there a way to update MPC with MHE in the same gekko class?

Tags: gekko

I am currently using an MPC to have the TCLab heater reach a certain set point temperature. I am trying to have an MHE update certain parameter values every 50 seconds. I have a previous MPC model that worked amazing and I tried to add a part in my main loop that has it switch to improve certain values and then switch back into MPC mode. I have seen that other people doing this same problem have made a gekko class for the MPC and also for the MHE and then had them work together, but is there a way that I can add a part in my current MPC loop that will allow the MHE to update certain values and then switch back into MPC?

Here is the Code that I added into my loop to have it update the variables but it isn't updating my values

```
 if i%50 == 0 or i == 0:

            m.options.IMODE = 5
            Q1.STATUS = 0
            Q1.FSTATUS = 1
            Q2.STATUS = 0
            Q2.FSTATUS = 1

            U.FSTATUS = 1
            α1.FSTATUS = 1
            α2.FSTATUS = 1
            τ.FSTATUS = 1

            m.solve(disp = False)

            Q1.STATUS = 1
            Q1.FSTATUS = 1
            Q2.STATUS = 1
            Q2.FSTATUS = 1


            m.options.IMODE = 6
            U.FSTATUS = 0
            α1.FSTATUS = 0
            α2.FSTATUS = 0
            τ.FSTATUS = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gekko facilitates transfer of information between MHE and MPC but combining them into a single application isn't a current feature. Warmstart files `est.t0` (MHE) and `ctl.t0` (MPC) store the prior solution and use it to initialize the next solve. A file `est.xfer` (MHE) is a transfer file to update the initial conditions and parameters from the MHE application. You can look at these files by opening the run folder if `remote=False` (local solve):

```py
mhe.open_folder()
mpc.open_folder()
```

**Why a Single Application is Challenging**

Gekko also uses a CSV file to transfer values and update the application before the next `m.solve()` command. Each variable `x` in Gekko only has one `x.value`. If you have an MHE and MPC application, you would need to manage how the `x.value` and all the options are reloaded for all of the variables before each of the `m.solve()` commands. It would be very tedious to manage that in a script, even with a `deepcopy()` function.

**Create MHE and MPC Models in a Loop**

An easier way is to create two separate models that are used for MHE and MPC. To facilitate this, the model can be built in a loop ([see complete example](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/TCLabH)) so that variables and equations are only defined once.

[image: MHE with MPC]

```py
# initialize MHE and MPC
mhe = GEKKO(name='tclab-mhe')
mpc = GEKKO(name='tclab-mpc')

# create 2 models (MHE and MPC) in loop
for m in [mhe,mpc]:
    # Adjustable Parameters
    # heat transfer (W/m2-K)
    m.U = m.FV(value=2.76,lb=1.0,ub=5.0)
    # Semi-fundamental correlations (energy balances)
    m.Equation(mass*Cp*m.TH1.dt() == m.U*A*(m.TaK-m.T1i) \
                  + eps * sigma * A * (m.TaK**4 - m.T1i**4) \
                  + m.Q_C12 + m.Q_R12 \
                  + m.alpha1 * m.Q1)
    # Empirical correlations (lag equations to emulate conduction)
    m.Equation(m.tau * m.TC1.dt() == -m.TC1 + m.TH1)
```

After the equations are defined, the MHE and MPC applications can be configured with various options that are specific to that mode.

**Application Specific Configuration**

```py
# ------------------------------
# Configure MHE
mhe.time = np.linspace(0,120,31)
mhe.options.IMODE   = 5 # MHE
# FV tuning
mhe.U.STATUS = 1
mhe.Ta.STATUS = 0
# ------------------------------
# Configure MPC
mpc.time = [0,4,8,12,15,20,25,30,35,40,50,60,70,80,90]
# FV tuning
mpc.U.STATUS = 0
mpc.Ta.STATUS = 0
mpc.U.FSTATUS = 1
mpc.Ta.FSTATUS = 1
# Global Options
mpc.options.IMODE   = 6 # MPC
```

If you'd like to easily transfer values between the MHE and MPC applications at every cycle then one option is to copy the `est.xfer` file from the MHE folder `mhe.path` into the MPC folder `mpc.path`. This will use the updated states and parameters from the MHE application in the MPC application.